# Dynamically format a cell

Tags: excel

I am creating an Excel Dashboard that returns Dollar Amounts in a specific cell based on a few List Selections.

What I need to do now is have the Cell dynamically format the Dollar Amount.

For example, if it returns $3,152,234.25 I want it to display $3.2M, but if it returns $756,253.67 then I want it to display $756K and so on.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following custom formatting:

> [>1000000]0.0,,\M;0.0,k

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly get one or the other with custom formats like this:

```
$0,"K";-$0,"K"
$0.00,,"M";-$0.00,,"M"
$0.00,,,"B";-$0.00,,,"B"
```

However, to have the conditions check for K/M/B, you would probably need a macro to dynamically set your formatting based on the values in the cells

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a particularly elegant solution, but you could use a formula like this:

```
=IF(A1/1000000>1,TEXT(A1/1000000,"$0.0")&"M",TEXT(A1/1000,"$0")&"K")
```

(Assumes your number is in cell A1)